# S3 Policy to grant AWS org child accounts access from AWS services (cloudFormation)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-policy

I'm trying to grant read only access for CloudFormation to some templates in a S3 Bucket.

I can do this when CF in the same account as the S3 bucket using `aws:PrincipalIsAWSService`. However, when I try to get this to work for any Child Accounts, I get permission denied.  I've tried adding the `PrincipalOrgID` or the Org account - but no joy so far.

I'm trying to avoid having to list ALL the child accounts, as they get added frequently, and was under the impression `PrincipalOrgID` was for this very purpose.

Any ideas?

```json
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:PrincipalOrgID": "o-yyyyyyyyyy"
                },
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:PrincipalIsAWSService": "true"
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you try just `aws:PrincipalOrgID`, without `PrincipalIsAWSService` condition ? Normally I didn't have problem when using the org check so far, so that check if it's a service might be an issue

Comment: Im pretty sure I did, but ill run it again and update.....

Comment: ‍♂️ @Caldazar Thats done it!   I thought I had checked that, but clearly not.  If you want to make that an answer I'll mark it as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving from comment to answer for visibility:

Problem was combination of conditions.

```
"StringEquals": {
            "aws:PrincipalOrgID": "o-yyyyyyyyyy"
        },
        "Bool": {
            "aws:PrincipalIsAWSService": "true"
        }
```

Just leaving

```
"StringEquals": {
    "aws:PrincipalOrgID": "o-yyyyyyyyyy"
  }
```

enables other accounts from the organization to access it.